# How to call class method in robot framework?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, robotframework

I am getting error "No keyword with name 'addition' found."

py file

```
class A:
  def addition(self,a,b):
      print(a+b)
obj=A()
obj.addition(4,5)
```

robot code

```
    *** Setting ***
Library  xyz.py

*** Test Cases ***
Addition Program
    addition    a    b
```

Comment: the code in the question is calling the method `checkadd` and this method does not exist. Are you sure that the error refers to the `addition` method that does exist ?

Comment: @D.L sorry that was my bad. just modified.I am not sure why it is giving me that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to follow the documentation to [RF](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-test-library-class-or-module)
.

Taken from the documentation:

- Library name
  The name of a test library that is used when a library is imported is the same as the name of the module or class implementing it. For example, if you have a Python module MyLibrary (that is, file MyLibrary.py), it will create a library with name MyLibrary.
  Python classes are always inside a module. If the name of a class implementing a library is the same as the name of the module, Robot Framework allows dropping the class name when importing the library. For example, class MyLib in MyLib.py file can be used as a library with just name MyLib. This also works with submodules so that if, for example, parent.MyLib module has class MyLib, importing it using just parent.MyLib works. If the module name and class name are different, libraries must be taken into use using both module and class names, such as mymodule.MyLibrary or parent.submodule.MyLib.*

Python file "MyLibrary.py"

```
class MyLibrary:

    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a=a
        self.b=b

    def addition(self):
        return self.a+self.b
```

robot file

```
*** Settings ***
Library           MyLibrary.py    ${2}    ${1}
  
*** Test Cases ***   
Example                
    ${result}=    MyLibrary.addition
    Log    ${result}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. But I wanted to take input from python file only i.e. I am passing values of a and b through python file. So is it possible to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Do you want to use python variable file?

Comment: I mean I want to pass variable value from python file only as i mentioned in my code. obj.addition(3,5) in this way and not from robot file.

Comment: i see you want to assign arguments upon creation of the library. That is also included in the documentation. i have updated the answer

Comment: Thank you worked for me. can I ask you one more question on this?

Comment: shure, go for it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72039044/how-to-pass-dataframe-as-argument-in-robot-file here I have question please check once.